# Exception has occurred: TclError can't use "icon.png" as iconphoto: not a photo image

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to figure out why this doesn't work.

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser
import urllib
import base64
import os
window=Tk()
def browser(url):
   webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
window.title("name")

if os.name == "nt":
   user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"
   url = "https://redstoner.me/downloads/gigashitfiles/gigashit.ico"
   headers = {"User-Agent" : user_agent,} 
   request = urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers)
   response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
   b64pic = base64.encodebytes(response.read())
   response.close()
   icondata= base64.b64decode(b64pic)
   tempFile= "icon.ico"
   iconfile= open(tempFile,"wb")
   iconfile.write(icondata)
   iconfile.close()
   window.wm_iconbitmap(tempFile)
   os.remove(tempFile)
else:
   user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"
   url = "https://redstoner.me/downloads/gigashitfiles/gigashit.png"
   headers = {"User-Agent" : user_agent,} 
   request = urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers)
   response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
   b64pic = base64.encodebytes(response.read())
   response.close()
   icondata= base64.b64decode(b64pic)
   tempFile= "icon.png"
   iconfile= open(tempFile,"wb")
   iconfile.write(icondata)
   iconfile.close()
   window.iconphoto(True, tempFile)
   os.remove(tempFile)

window.geometry("650x700")
window.mainloop()
```

First of all, I know I could of made this way cleaner but right now I really wanna find out how to get rid of the error.
I tried using tk.call but it didn't work also.

Error is at line 40, in 
window.iconphoto(True, tempFile)

Comment: Why are you Base64 encoding then decoding the data, rather than writing it directly to the file?  And `iconphoto()` doesn't want a filename, it wants a `PhotoImage` object loaded from the file.

Comment: `iconphoto` requires an instance of `PhotoImage`, not a filename, which is pretty much what the error is telling you.